# Excel functions in macros

Tags: vba, excel

How to use excel functions in macros?

I want to extract the month out of date format:

```
k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Month(Selection.Value)
```

Should this not work?

Comment: Why worksheet function? And not this? `Debug.Print Format(Selection.Value, "m")` OR `Debug.Print Month(Selection.Value)`

Answer (score 3):

When a worksheet function like MONTH has an exact equivalent native to VBA then its not available through Application.WorksheetFunction and you have to use the native VBA function as Siddarth has shown

```
k=Month(Selection.Value)
```

Comment: Comments can be deleted. I suggest editing so that you actually include the answer!

Comment: +1 the worksheet functions which are available through the `WorksheetFunction` object are listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822194.aspx